# Visual Studio 2013 Express and Windows Store App does not start

Tags: windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I have a really weird issue that will make me crazy soon I think.

I've installed Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows to test Windows Store Apps development. I want to use XAML and C#. So, I created a new project from the blank app template and just try to start it. Unfortunatelly it has never worked, the screen stay blocked on the splash screen of my app. No errors in Visual Studio, it just try to launch a Visual Studio Just in Time debbuger for an unhandled exception in .Net framework, but when I select the debugger nohthing happen. There's no trace of an exception in the EventViewer either...I tried local machine and simulator debug...no change !

Sometime i have this message in Visual Studio too but it's not all the time[image] :

I tried everything I found on the internet :

- Reset VS settings
- Renew developper license
  (...)

When I make a new Windows Store App with Javascript it works perfectly..it seems to be only a XAML/C# issue.

Any help would be much appreciated ! Thank you in advance !

My configuration :

- Windows 8.1
- Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Update 1
- SSD drive, Intel i7, Lenovo IdeaPad

Comment: maybe [this](http://michaelcrump.net/resolution-unable-to-activate-windows-store-app-the-activation-request-failed-with-error-e-fail) can help

Comment: Thanks Omar but it has not worked for me !

Comment: Have you tried restarting the computer or Visual Studio? This sometimes happens to me if the debugger is trying to write to a file with a lock on it (sometimes the debugger is bad at giving it up if it crashes).

Comment: Yes I did everything I could to fix this issue...I resolved it today by formatting and re-installing my whole PC...and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it by re-installating all the system. I suppose there was something wrong with the .net Framework. Now it worked well !

EDIT : 
I found that was messing the whole system. If I install SQL Server 2012 Express Edition it stop working. So...I switch to another DBMS !